# How to increase dots size and join dots

Tags: plotting

I tried to build graphic using ListPlot
Code:

```
rand1 = RandomReal[1, 10];

rand2 = RandomReal[1, 10];

Data1 = List[{Part[rand1[[1]]], Part[rand2[[1]]]}];
Data2 = List[{Part[rand1[[2]]], Part[rand2[[2]]]}];
Data3 = List[{Part[rand1[[3]]], Part[rand2[[3]]]}];
Data4 = List[{Part[rand1[[4]]], Part[rand2[[4]]]}];
Data5 = List[{Part[rand1[[5]]], Part[rand2[[5]]]}];
Data6 = List[{Part[rand1[[6]]], Part[rand2[[6]]]}];
Data7 = List[{Part[rand1[[7]]], Part[rand2[[7]]]}];
Data8 = List[{Part[rand1[[8]]], Part[rand2[[8]]]}];
Data9 = List[{Part[rand1[[9]]], Part[rand2[[9]]]}];
Data10 = List[{Part[rand1[[10]]], Part[rand2[[10]]]}];

ListPlot[{Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5, Data6, Data7, Data8, 
Data9, Data10}, PlotLegends -> PointLegend
[
Automatic, {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"} , 
LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendLabel -> "Data:"], 
PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], Frame -> True,
FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 16], 
Style["y", FontSize -> 16]},
PlotRange -> {All, All}, FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {All, All}}, 
ImageSize -> 1000
]
```

As a result I got:
[image]

How I can to increase dots size and how I can to join dots?
I tried to use PlotLegent->PointSize[] and Joined->True and it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `Disk[]`? One of the arguments for that is the size. That's where I'd start at least. I haven't made a scatter graph on here, but that's how I solved my need to control point size!
Let me know if it helps/works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[0]

data = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}] // Sort;
```

`data` is sorted to keep line from criss-crossing.

```
len = Length[data];

colors = ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range[len];

Legended[
 ListPlot[
  List /@ Tooltip /@ data, (* make each point a separate data set *)
   PlotMarkers -> (Style["•", 50, #] & /@ colors),
  Prolog -> {Gray, Line[data]},
  ImageSize -> 800],
 PointLegend[colors, Range[len],
  LegendFunction -> "Frame",
  LegendLabel -> "Data:",
  LegendMarkerSize -> Large,
  LegendMargins -> {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @John - Does increasing `LegendMarkerSize` do enough? Also changed `Epilog` to `Prolog` so that line is not drawn on top of `PlotMarkers`